# jquery fade back in on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to make "slider.$controls" fade to opacity .1 on a timeout which works perfectly, I just cant seem to get it to return to opacity 1.0 on mouseover.

```
$(function () {
    var fadeTime = 1750,
        fadeDelay = 4000,
        // hide after 3 second delay
        timer, hideControls = function (slider) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            setTimeout(function () {
                slider.$controls.fadeTo(fadeTime, 0.1);
                slider.$controls.mouseOver.fadeTo(fadeTime, 1.0);
                $('.tooltip').fadeOut(fadeTime);
            }, fadeDelay);
        };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
slider.$controls.hover(function () {

    // mouseenter
    $(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, 1.0);
}, function () {

    // mouseleave
    $(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, 0.1);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 1):

.mouseOver.fadeTo is not possible, use a event:

```
slider.$controls.mouseover(function() {
  $(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, 1);
});
```

Or is slider.$controls.mouseOver a propertie?